# Grouped and stacked bar charts in Python Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, visualization

[sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hXW6O1y2Kr9vpP0p5C3IgDeZCuOOlvkn/view?usp=sharing)

I am attempting to create a bar chart such that the stacked according to duration interval and is grouped by behavior type, per this example - https://community.plotly.com/t/grouped-stacked-bar-chart/60805

My code is only displaying the data from the final variable "SIB" and nothing else and I'm not exactly sure why. It seem to be getting overwritten in the loop, even though my data is structured in the same format as the example. Can someone please help determine why the other data does not appear on the plot?

```
df = pd.read_pickle("data_save")

print(df.head())

# Create a figure with the right layout
fig = go.Figure(
    layout=go.Layout(
        height=600,
        width=1000,
        barmode="relative",
        yaxis_showticklabels=False,
        yaxis_showgrid=False,
        yaxis_range=[0, df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum().max().max()],
       # Secondary y-axis overlayed on the primary one and not visible
        yaxis2=go.layout.YAxis(
            visible=False,
            matches="y",
            overlaying="y",
            anchor="x",
        ),
        font=dict(size=24),
        legend_x=0,
        legend_y=1,
        legend_orientation="h",
        hovermode="x",
        margin=dict(b=0,t=10,l=0,r=10)
    )
)

# Define some colors for the product, revenue pairs
colors = {
    "Aggression" : {
        "Duration: 0" : "#F7FF00",
        "Duration: 11-15": "#D6DD00",
        "Duration: 16-20": "#BAC100",
        "Duration: 20+": "#9CA200",
        "Duration: 6-10": "#838800",
        "Duration: <5": "#6A6E00",
    },
    "Disruptive" : {
        "Duration: 0" : "#00FF08",
        "Duration: 11-15": "#00ED07",
        "Duration: 16-20": "#00D006",
        "Duration: 20+": "#00AD05",
        "Duration: 6-10": "#008C04",
        "Duration: <5": "#006A03",
    },
    "SIB" : {
        "Duration: 0" : "#00D8FF",
        "Duration: 11-15": "#00BCDE",
        "Duration: 16-20": "#00A7C6",
        "Duration: 20+": "#0089A3",
        "Duration: 6-10": "#006D82",
        "Duration: <5": "#005262",
    },
    "Self Mutilation" : {
        "Duration: 0" : "#FF0000",
        "Duration: 11-15": "#F00202",
        "Duration: 16-20": "#CA0000",
        "Duration: 20+": "#AF0000",
        "Duration: 6-10": "#900000",
        "Duration: <5": "#6C0000",
    },
}

# Add the traces
for i, t in enumerate(colors):
    for j, col in enumerate(df[t].columns):
        if (df[t][col] == 0).all():
            continue
        fig.add_bar(
            x=df.index,
            y=df[t][col],
            # Set the right yaxis depending on the selected product (from enumerate)
            yaxis=f"y{i + 1}",
            # Offset the bar trace, offset needs to match the width
            # The values here are in milliseconds, 1billion ms is ~1/3 month
            offsetgroup=str(i),
            offset=(i - 1) * 1000000000,
            width=100000000,
            legendgroup=t,
            legendgrouptitle_text=t,
            name=col,
            marker_color=colors[t][col],
            marker_line=dict(width=2, color="#333"),
            hovertemplate="%{y}<extra></extra>"
        )

fig.show()
```

[figure created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljA3e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing only the "SIB" variable is in relation to how the yaxis is being set with `yaxis=f"y{i + 1}"`.

There can be only 2 yaxes and currently it is being passed 4 values. If you remove that line all of the data will be plotted on the left y axis.

Below is the code with that line commented out.

```
# Create a figure with the right layout
fig = go.Figure(
    layout=go.Layout(
        height=600,
        width=1000,
        barmode="relative",
        yaxis_showticklabels=False,
        yaxis_showgrid=False,
        yaxis_range=[0, df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum().max().max() * 1.5],
       # Secondary y-axis overlayed on the primary one and not visible
        yaxis2=go.layout.YAxis(
            visible=False,
            matches="y",
            overlaying="y",
            anchor="x",
        ),
        font=dict(size=24),
        legend_x=0,
        legend_y=1,
        legend_orientation="h",
        hovermode="x",
        margin=dict(b=0,t=10,l=0,r=10)
    )
)

# Define some colors for the product, revenue pairs
colors = {
    "Self Mutilation" : {
        "Duration: 0" : "#FF0000",
        "Duration: 11-15": "#F00202",
        "Duration: 16-20": "#CA0000",
        "Duration: 20+": "#AF0000",
        "Duration: 6-10": "#900000",
        "Duration: <5": "#6C0000",
    },
    "SIB" : {
        "Duration: 0" : "#00D8FF",
        "Duration: 11-15": "#00BCDE",
        "Duration: 16-20": "#00A7C6",
        "Duration: 20+": "#0089A3",
        "Duration: 6-10": "#006D82",
        "Duration: <5": "#005262",
    },
    "Aggression" : {
        "Duration: 0" : "#F7FF00",
        "Duration: 11-15": "#D6DD00",
        "Duration: 16-20": "#BAC100",
        "Duration: 20+": "#9CA200",
        "Duration: 6-10": "#838800",
        "Duration: <5": "#6A6E00",
    },
    "Disruptive" : {
        "Duration: 0" : "#00FF08",
        "Duration: 11-15": "#00ED07",
        "Duration: 16-20": "#00D006",
        "Duration: 20+": "#00AD05",
        "Duration: 6-10": "#008C04",
        "Duration: <5": "#006A03",
    },
}

# Add the traces
for i, t in enumerate(colors):
    for j, col in enumerate(df[t].columns):
        if (df[t][col] == 0).all():
            continue
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=df.index,
            y=df[t][col],
            # Set the right yaxis depending on the selected product (from enumerate)
            #yaxis=f"y{i + 1}",
            # Offset the bar trace, offset needs to match the width
            # The values here are in milliseconds, 1billion ms is ~1/3 month
            offsetgroup=str(i),
            offset=(i - 1) * 1000000000,
            width=100000000,
            legendgroup=t,
            legendgrouptitle_text=t,
            name=col,
            marker_color=colors[t][col],
            marker_line=dict(width=2, color="#333"),
            hovertemplate="%{y}<extra></extra>"
                            )
                    )

fig.show()
```

When you run the code now you will see that all data is represented, albeit messily, in the figure. I'd recommend working with the offset variables.